# Calculating a rolling weighted sum using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, moving-average, rolling-computation

I am curious to know if there are any more optimal ways to compute this "rolling weighted sum" (unsure what the actual terminology is, but I will provide an example to further clarify). I am asking this because I am certain that my current code snippet is not coded in the most optimal way with respect to memory usage, and there is opportunity to improve its performance by using numpy's more advanced functions.

Example:

```
import numpy as np

A = np.append(np.linspace(0, 1, 10), np.linspace(1.1, 2, 30))
np.random.seed(0)

B = np.random.randint(3, size=40) + 1

# list of [(weight, (lower, upper))]
d = [(1, (-0.25, -0.20)), (0.5, (-0.20, -0.10)), (2, (-0.10, 0.15))]
```

In Python 3.7:

```
## A
array([0.        , 0.11111111, 0.22222222, 0.33333333, 0.44444444,
       0.55555556, 0.66666667, 0.77777778, 0.88888889, 1.        ,
       1.1       , 1.13103448, 1.16206897, 1.19310345, 1.22413793,
       1.25517241, 1.2862069 , 1.31724138, 1.34827586, 1.37931034,
       1.41034483, 1.44137931, 1.47241379, 1.50344828, 1.53448276,
       1.56551724, 1.59655172, 1.62758621, 1.65862069, 1.68965517,
       1.72068966, 1.75172414, 1.78275862, 1.8137931 , 1.84482759,
       1.87586207, 1.90689655, 1.93793103, 1.96896552, 2.        ])

## B
array([1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2,
       1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 1, 2, 2, 3, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 3, 1, 3])
```

Expected Solution:

```
array([ 6. ,  6.5,  8. , 10.5, 12. , 11. , 11.5, 11.5,  6.5, 13.5, 25. ,
       27.5, 30.5, 34.5, 37.5, 36. , 35. , 35. , 34. , 34.5, 34. , 36.5,
       33. , 34. , 34.5, 34.5, 36. , 39. , 37. , 36. , 37. , 36.5, 37.5,
       39. , 36.5, 37.5, 34. , 31. , 27.5, 23. ])
```

The logic I want to translate into code:

Let's look at how `10.5` (the fourth element in the expected solution) is computed. `d` represents a collection of nested tuples with first float element `weight`, and second tuple element `bounds` (in the form of `(lower, upper)`).

We look at the fourth element of `A` (`0.33333333`) and apply `bounds` for each tuple in `d`. For the first tuple in `d`:

```
0.33333333 + (-0.25) = 0.08333333
0.33333333 + (-0.20) = 0.13333333
```

We go back to `A` to see if there are any elements between bounds `(0.08333333, 0.1333333)`. Because the second element of `A` (`0.11111111`) falls in this range, we pull the second element of `B` (`2`) and multiply it by its weight from `d` (`1`) and add it to the second element of the expected output.

After iterating across all tuples in `d`, the fourth element of the expected output is computed as:

```
1 * 2 + 0.5 * 1 + 2 * (2 + 2) = 10.5
```

Here is my attempted code:

```
D = np.zeros(len(A))
for v in d:
    weight, (_lower, _upper) = v
    lower, upper = A + _lower, A + _upper
    _A = np.tile(A, (len(A), 1))
    __A = np.bitwise_and(_A > lower.reshape(-1, 1), _A < upper.reshape(-1, 1))
    D += weight * (__A @ B)
D
```

Hopefully this makes sense. Please feel free to ask clarifying questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since intervals (-0.25, -0.20), (-0.20, -0.10) and (-0.10, 0.15) are actually subintervals of [partition of an interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_of_an_interval) (-0.25, 0.15) you could [find indices](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) where elements should be inserted in A to maintain order. They specify [slices of B to perform](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) addition on. In short:

```
partition = np.array([-0.25, -0.20, -0.10, 0.15])
weights = np.array([1, 0.5, 2])
out = []
for n in A:
    idx = np.searchsorted(A, n + partition)
    results = np.add.reduceat(B[:idx[-1]], idx[:-1])
    out.append(np.dot(results, weights))
>>> print(out)
[7.5, 7.5, 8.0, 10.5, 12.0, 11.0, 11.5, 11.5, 6.5, 13.5, 27.5, 27.5, 31.5, 35.5, 37.5, 37.0, 36.0, 35.0, 34.0, 34.5, 34.0, 36.5, 33.0, 34.0, 34.5, 34.5, 36.0, 39.0, 37.0, 36.0, 37.0, 36.5, 37.5, 39.0, 36.5, 37.5, 34.0, 31.0, 27.5, 23.0]
```

Note that `results` are wrong if there are empty slices of `B`

Comment: Thanks for a great first response! I really do like how you defined `partition` and `weights` since the assumptions you made applies to my problem. It's also a cleaner solution that reduces memory costs. Just wondering, is there any way to use numpy vectorization to avoid using a `for` loop across elements of `A` ? Thanks!

Comment: A bottleneck here is `np.add.reduceat` method. Usually, `for` loop could be vectorised if you are able to find a way to replace commands to work with a flattened variant of array instead. `for n in A: idx = np.searchsorted(A, n + partition)` part is easy, you could replace it with `np.searchsorted(A, partition + A[:, None])` and call [`ravel`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) method on it if needed. I only don't know what to do with this `np.add.reduceat` part, it looks complicated to apply it over an axis of 2D array. I will take a look if I have more time.

Comment: I found a solution that is inspired by your solution. I will mark yours as most helpful since you provided me enough guidance to figure it out myself. I will post my solution here! Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for collaboration. Indeed, it's nice to see `np.add.reduceat` replaced by stride tricks. I'm not sure if `np.apply_along_axis` helps to gain speed though because you still need to apply some method step by step. If you want a faster looping, take a look at `numba`. Usually it outperforms `numpy`.

Answer (score 0):

Credits to @mathfux for providing me enough guidance. Here's the final code solution that I developed based on conversations here:

```
partition = np.array([-0.25, -0.20, -0.10, 0.15])
weights = np.array([1, 0.5, 2])
idx = np.searchsorted(A, partition + A[:, None])
_idx = np.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view(idx, 2, axis = 1)
values = np.apply_along_axis(lambda x: B[slice(*(x))].sum(), 2, _idx)
values @ weights
```